# Eclipse CDT in Linux very slow opening Build setting for arm cross compiler

Tags: eclipse, arm, eclipse-cdt

I have a weird problems I can't seem to figure out. My eclipse takes very very long about 2 minutes to open the build setting under project preference. This only happens when I am doing ARM cross compiling. If I open the build setting for regular Linux GCC it's fast.

Environment is as follows

- Linux 64Bit
- Oracle JDK 8
- JDK running in RAM disk
- Arm cross compiler

How do I see what eclipse is doing, I really can't figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seem to be based on the gtk version 3 that is used by default to open eclipse. The same topic had been discussed inside the following forum:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203603

Eclipse can be forced to use a previous version gtk version by editing the eclipse.ini file of the installation folder. Just place the lines

```
 --launcher.GTK_version
2
```

right before the line  **--launcher.appendVmargs**.